# Alignment changes on entering text within a div with display inline-block

Tags: html, css, alignment

Stuck on a problem where when I enter text in a div with display property set to inline-block. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="section">
    <div class="sectionheading">
    </div>
    <div class="sectionheading">
    </div>
    <div class="sectionheading">
    </div>
    <div class="sectionheading" id="sectionheading">
        <span>Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sectionheading {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #df5e5e;
    height:35px;
}

#sectionheading {
    width: 150px !important;
}

#section {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

The problem is with the div having id 'sectionheading'. When I have text in it like in the HTML given it shifts downwards for some reason, however when the div is empty it is aligned properly with the other divs. What's the problem here?

Comment: could you provide the same in a fiddle would be easier to help you

Comment: looks like it, vertical-align: top solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;` will solve your issue.

If you are using `display: inline-block;` you need to set `vertical:align` property of the div. Because default it's `vertical-align`  value is `baseline`.

```
.sectionheading {
    background-color: #df5e5e;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 6px;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/godcyvj5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k9y8ku7d/)**

```
.sectionheading {   
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for solve this issue..

```css
.sectionheading {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #df5e5e;
    height:35px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#sectionheading {
    width: 150px !important;
   
}

#section {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="section">
    <div class="sectionheading">
    </div>
    <div class="sectionheading">
    </div>
    <div class="sectionheading">
    </div>
    <div class="sectionheading" id="sectionheading">
        <span>Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why such happens when there is text is because there is a height given by default and with no proper padding height added. You can either add `vertical-align: top;` or add `line-height: 24px;` and remove `height`.

Fiddle : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/godcyvj5/2/)